# barycentre in hyperbolic geometry :

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

In euclidean geometry we know the formulas for midpoint and barycentre of a finite set of points, so can we find similar formulas in hyperbolic geometry ?  In the Klein disk, Ungar cited in his book "A gyrovector space approach to Hyperbolic geoemtry" that the barycentroid of $(u,v,w)$ is given by
$$m_{uvw}= \frac{\gamma_uu+\gamma_v v+\gamma_w w}{\gamma_u+\gamma_v +\gamma_w } $$
with $\gamma_u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\|u\|2}}$ the Lorentz factor.
I am looking for simple formulas without using $\gamma_u$, so is this possible?

Comment: Is that formula the definition of the barycentroid? Or is there an independent definition from which that formula is derived? Without knowing that, your question is hard to answer.

Comment: Hi Mr Lee, sorry for my late answer .  That formula is a the theorem 3.35 page 85 in Ungar's book "A gyrovector space approach to Hyperbolic geoemtry".

Comment: I think I have to start by proving a similar formula for the midpoint $m_{uv}=\frac{\gamma_u u+\gamma_v v}{\gamma_u+\gamma_v}$ which is in the theorem 3.33 in the same book

Answer (score 0):

Converting from the Klein disk to the hyperboloid model maps a point $p = (x, y)$ to $p_H = (\gamma_px, \gamma_py, \gamma_p)$. So in the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry, this formula simplifies to

$$m_{uvw} = \frac{u+v+w}{\|u+v+w\|}$$

where $\|(x,y,t)\| := \sqrt{|x^2+y^2-t^2|}$ denotes the Minkowski "norm".